# Emacs Lisp - opening new window

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to write an emacs lisp function that will write output to a window other than the current window.  It should create a new window if only the current one exists, and it should use an existing one otherwise.  This is similar to what happens when you run C-h-f (Describe Function), and the description pops up in another window.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

See [`display-buffer`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window.html):

> display-buffer is an interactive
>   compiled Lisp function in `window.el'.
>
> It is bound to C-x 4 C-o.
>
> (display-buffer buffer-or-name
>   &optional not-this-window frame)
>
> Make buffer buffer-or-name appear in
>   some window but don't select it.
>   buffer-or-name must be a buffer or the
>   name of an existing buffer.  Return
>   the window chosen to display
>   buffer-or-name or nil if no such
>   window is found.
>
> Optional argument not-this-window
>   non-nil means display the buffer in a
>   window other than the selected one,
>   even if it is already displayed in the
>   selected window.
>
> Optional argument frame specifies
>   which frames to investigate when the
>   specified buffer is already displayed.
>   If the buffer is already displayed in
>   some window on one of these frames
>   simply return that window.  Possible
>   values of frame are:
>
> `visible' - consider windows on all
>   visible frames.
>
> 0 - consider windows on all visible or
>   iconified frames.
>
> t - consider windows on all frames.
>
> A specific frame - consider windows on
>   that frame only.
>
> nil - consider windows on the selected
>   frame (actually the last
>   non-minibuffer frame) only.  If,
>   however, either
>   `display-buffer-reuse-frames' or`
>   pop-up-frames' is non-nil (non-nil
>   and not graphic-only on a text-only
>   terminal), consider all visible or
>   iconified frames.

Or you can use `pop-to-buffer` if you want that buffer to be selected (which it sounds like you don't), or `with-output-to-temp-buffer` which binds the `standard-output` to be sent to the temporary buffer - read the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Temporary-Displays) for more details (hat tip to [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514187/michael-gummelt) for that).

Comment: Thanks. I also found with-output-to-temp-buffer.  It allows direct input into the temporary buffer, rather than keeping track of a separate buffer.

Comment: @Michael added with documentation link.